# How to use a javascript library in dart?

Tags: javascript, dart, dart-pub

I was wondering how to use a javascript library in dart ? There are several examples in the web but either they do not work, or they are super verbose, and they are all at least 2 years old.

I want to use the D3 library in my case

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The likely simplest method of using javascript in dart is to use immediately is the [`dart:js`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-js/dart-js-library.html) library, where you can use `context.callMethod` to call methods in javascript.

Ex.

```dart
import 'dart:js';

main() => context.callMethod('alert', ['Hello from Dart!']);//'alert' is the function name, the second parameter is a `List` of arguments passed to the function.
```

---

Alternatively, you can use [`package:js`](https://pub.dev/packages/js), which should usually be used and provides higher level functionality, but it may be harder to start using because the documentation is a bit spotty. This library uses annotations with the external keyword to handle dart-JS interop.

Ex.

```dart
@JS()
library stringify;

import 'package:js/js.dart';

// Calls invoke JavaScript `JSON.stringify(obj)`.
@JS('JSON.stringify')
external String stringify(Object obj);
```

With this, you can then call `stringify` elsewhere and static analysis will be able to better pick up on type errors because you can explicitly define parameter and return types.

Comment: How did you know to set the library to `stringify` ?

Comment: @DanMossa That snippet is directly from the docs for the package I linked. I don't believe the library name matters at all. If you were trying to access a particular JS namespace the `library <>;` wouldn't matter still, but what's in the `@JS` annotation would.